# Solving differential equation invariant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have eqn: $\frac{dx}{dt} = -y(t)$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = x(t)$

I know that $(x(0),y(0))= (1,0)$.

I want to solve eqn and show that it admits an invariant $I = x(t)^2 + y(t)^2$.

I know $x' = -y$,

$y' = x$,

$x^{\prime\prime} = -y' = -x$

I know general solution of $x" = -x$ is
$x = a\sin x = b\cos x$.

I know 
$x(0) = a\sin 0 + b\cos 0 = 1$
So $b = 1$

How can I show $a = 1$? (I think it should!)

I tried $x' = a\cos x - b\sin x$ since $y = -x$ but it just gives $ a = 0$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Answer (score 1):

You have $\frac{dx}{dt} = -y(t)$ and $x(t)=a\sin(t)+\cos(t)$ so take the derivative and use $y(0)=0$.

You will find $a=0$, as you have already discovered but do not believe.  If you had $a=1$ then you would not have $y(0)=0$.

So you have $(x(t),y(t)) = \left((\cos(t),-\sin(t)\right)$.  This is a [parametric equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) of a [circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) of radius $1$ centred on the origin.

Comment: Are you sure its -sin?

Comment: How does this show the invariant though?

Comment: @sam: on your first comment, perhaps it is $+\sin(t)$, and you should check and decide.  On your second comment, $(\cos t)^2 + (\sin t)^2=1$ is constant.

Comment: I know that it is constant. But why did you square it?

Comment: @sam (a) It is not true unless it involves squares (Pythagoras).  (b) Your question said "it admits an invariant $I = x(t)^2 + y(t)^2$."